# How do I get Soil Data into ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, attribute-joins, fields-attributes

I work for a small civil engineering firm in Florida and part of our due diligence on our sites was checking the soil types. Previously, I was using FGDL (a Florida based GIS data clearinghouse) where it was just easy to download the soils data by county and bring it into our maps that way. Well, I went to download some new counties recently and discovered they no longer carry NRCS (National Resources Conservation Service) soils data. I tried going directly to NRCS and download them myself, only to discover that someone at FGDL was linking the spatial data to the tabular data for me and I have zero idea how to do any of that. I've spent most of my day today after lunch trying to figure it out and now I'm desperate for some help. I don't have access to Microsoft Access, which it looks like one might need to connect the data. So I am not sure what to do next. I am a team of 1 at my office, so no one would be able to offer me answers on site. So, How do I get workable Soil Data into ArcMap?

Comment: I took a quick look at the USDA/NRCS website and [downloaded Alachua County](https://websoilsurvey.sc.egov.usda.gov/App/WebSoilSurvey.aspx). The spatial was included with the download. Might not be the case with all counties as the website suggests that not all counties have spatial. You'll have to contact the person listed in the metadata file to get more information if the spatial doesn't exist and assistance with how the Access database is meant to work is also listed in the metadata.

Comment: @danagerous NRCS soils data (SSURGO, gSSURGO, & STATSGO) is also available via the [Geospatial Data Gateway](https://gdg.sc.egov.usda.gov/). One of the feature classes included with the gSSURGO product is the soil survey areas, which is linked to a table with each area's development status.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of downloading the data for a single soil survey area, you may want to get the gSSURGO product for the state. It will be in File Geodatabase format instead of MDB, and has relationship classes built for the tables. There are also [gSSURGO tools available](https://www.nrcs.usda.gov/wps/portal/nrcs/detail/soils/survey/geo/?cid=nrcs142p2_053628) for ArcGIS 10 that duplicate many of the capabilities of the [SSURGO Soil Data Viewer](https://www.nrcs.usda.gov/wps/portal/nrcs/detail/soils/home/?cid=nrcs142p2_053620) add-in.

For more help you can contact either the NRCS State Soil Scientist or GIS Specialist. They can be reached through the Contact Us section of their [web site](https://www.nrcs.usda.gov/wps/portal/nrcs/site/fl/home/).